# Regex java to check for starting [ and ending ] but could have \t\r\n at start and end

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to check that a String starts with `[` and ends with `]` but allowing whitespace before/after the square brackets.

I could use `trim()`, then check the end characters, but the String can be very long (more than 100,000 chars) so it could be expensive to create a new trimmed String. I want to know what is the best approach that gives reasonable performance given the large String size.

Sample input that should pass:

```
"\t\n\r      [  (very long string) ] \t \r \n"
```

Using regex, I have the following expression, but don't know if it is absolutely correct or not, or if it will perform well.

```
(^|\s+)\[((.*)|\s)+\]($|\s+)
```

What is the best approach for solving this?

Comment: Why not use `startsWith` and `endsWith`?

Comment: That means it have to call trim() first.

Comment: What makes you think your regex may not be correct? If it passes all test cases you can think of, then it's "OK"

Comment: Using regex would likely be slower than using trim here, though

Comment: @user I doubt it. Regex doesn't need to create a new string, and it's pretty. darn fast.

Comment: @Bohemian `(^|\s+)\[((.*)|\s)+\]($|\s+)` is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/WuqQp5/1) of a very poorly written regex prone to catastrophic backtracking. I suspect it could be more expensive NOT to copy the String. To give any answer, we'd need more details though.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many whitespace characters there can be at the ends?

Comment: There is no limit on the whitespace or \n or \t. But this regex (^|\s+)\[((.*)|\s)+\]($|\s+)  has shown a very bad performance. Could someone help on fixing the regex to have better perf than trim() and startWith and endWith?

Comment: @Lazyworm so there could be say 50,000 whitespace chars before the first `[`, and another 50,000 following the last `]`?

Comment: It could be. But that is quite extreme case. For normal case, I would say like 10 - 50. But the regex I have is taking a very long time.

Comment: The strange part is if I don't have space in front or back, the regex perf is worse than trim(). If I add a few more space the front or back, the time taken is exponentially increase.

Comment: How often are you doing this check?  Copying 100,000 characters with `trim()` is a trivial expense if you’re doing it less than once per second.

Comment: I am doing it for up to 10,000 transaction per second.

Comment: I thought regex is always perf better than trim, but it doesn't seem to be true for all cases. Not sure why it takes much longer and even crash some online regex tester when I have more than 10 or 20 spaces in front or end?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast JavaScript version, can be easily applied to Java as well:

```js
var result = /^\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*$/.test('\t\n\r    [...very long string...] \t \r \n');
console.log('result: ' + result);
```

Notes on this regex:

- use anchors (`^` and `$`) to allow only leading & trailing white-space
- use `\s*` instead of `\s+` because with the latter you need an *OR* test for empty white-space
- use a fast `[^\]]*` to avoid the expensive `.*` regex with backtracking

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, it showing me it takes 700313 nano second, compare to trim used 50000 nano.

Comment: So you do a trim, followed by a regex test for `[` and `]`? By all means, use the fastest method :-)